# Where is the LightSwitch Reporting Capability

Tags: reporting, visual-studio-lightswitch

Just what good is a tool for building business systems that provdes alot of ways to get data in and no way to get data out?!?

Am I missing something here? I'm just delving into LightSwitch.

Did Microsoft seriously provide a tool for creating depertmental business systems (a more enterprise / backup friendly replacement for all the little Access apps floating around) and NOT provide any kind of reporting solution?

It almost seems impossily ignorant given the fact that this is all based on SQL Server and SSRS is at their fingertips?

In all my searches I find discussion of 3rd party components and workarounds to achieve what is surely a key required feature of such a tool.

Someone please point me in the direction of the canned reporting functionality that I am overlooking or help me to understand the logic in a one way (data goes in but never out) business system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reasons that many of us can't even begin to fathom, Microsoft did indeed leave reporting out of LS V1. So you're not "missing" anything obvious.

From your searches, you've probably seen most of the "workarounds" that people have come up with, including the $99 DevExpress offering (which I can't personally recommend, but I've seen others say they think it's worth the money spent).

We're HOPING that this will have been adressed by V2, but there's no guarantee that will be the case. There must have been a "good reason" that SOMEONE thought was OK to leave out reporting, but the rest of us are just as dumbfounded by the decision as you are.

Microsoft have certainly HEARD what all of us have had to say about it, it's now up to them to do something about the situation. We'll just have to wait & see.